# When setting up internal links, can you link to a single page too often?

Tags: seo, links, link-building

I made a website for a client about tourist services he offers.

There is a blog, with unique content where each service is described. For example, there are 40 hotels, so there is 40 unique blog articles, giving basic info about hotels.

5 main pages are for each service, one of them is for booking hotel accommodation.

If I link all 40 blog articles about hotels to main page where hotels are booked will this be good or bad thing?

I have read a lot about interlinking but am not sure if you can "overdo it", or is this important at all?

Comment: Both answers are right. It is only 40 pages. But also think about user experience (UX) and signaling important to search engines. Is it good for the user? If yes, then go for it. If you think it is important to signal to search engines that these are important pages, more so than the others, then go for it. But there is a limit too. If in the future you begin to approach about 200 links, then you will want to avoid this idea. Google does have a limit that changes and it is not a hard limit. It is part of the anti-spam mechanism. I would start getting concerned as I approached 100 links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most websites have many links to important pages:

- The home page  is usually linked from the logo on every page
- The login page usually has lots of links
- The privacy policy and terms of service are usually linked in the footer of every page
- There is usually main navigation on every page

There is nothing wrong with linking to certain pages a lot.   Almost all websites do it.  It won't hurt your search engine rankings.

Answer (score 2):

Don't link all to the same page. Give relevant meta title to each sub pages of website. 
And the give interlinking according to the keywords and blog posts. Relevancy is important.

Comment: Each blog post is very relevant to main page where booking is done. On booking page i also have text that talks in general about hotels in the area, and blogs are more detailed about each hotel in the area. That is the reason why i ask, to me it makes sense to have a link from each blog to booking page, but having 40 links seems to much. But again not sure how many is good.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=website+internal+linking+structure&biw=1366&bih=653&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=9xhzVMaeMYWOuASB04D4Cw&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=ygeYTovUGLTAKM%253A%3BG7exmMT2_yGQ-M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.wikiweb.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2014%252F05%252Finternal-link.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.wikiweb.com%252Finternal-linking-structure%252F%3B451%3B278

Comment: This video cleared it up a bit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ybpXU0ckKQ. I guess it wont hurt to have 40 links "book now", and it will help user to find a way to book for accomodation.